# When I do a git pull with rebase, how do I disable the rebase hook?

Tags: git, git-rebase, githooks, git-pull

The command:

```
git rebase --no-verify
```

...allows me to rebase without running the git rebase hook I've created.

But I've also set **git pull** to rebase instead of merge, so now when I do a pull, it runs my rebase trigger. Is there a way to pass the --no-verify option to git pull and have it use the option when rebasing?

(Other than the last resort of creating a wrapper script to temporarily move the triggers out of the way, and move them back again afterwards).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could do it in two steps:

```
git fetch <remote> <branch>
git rebase <remote>/<branch> --no-verify
```

These two operations are synonymous with `git pull --rebase` or the `git pull` that is configured to use rebase instead of a merge. You could also create an alias that groups these two actions into one and call it `pull-no-verify` or something like that.